# Prestashop 1.7.1.1 multilanguage redirect issue

Tags: redirect, prestashop, cart

I am experiencing a problem with a Prestashop website.

When I try to access the cart page (domain.com/cart), the page redirects to the homepage. This also happens when I go to "domain.com/index.php?controller=cart".

This is only happening for the cart page and when I look at network activity in chrome's devtools, I see that there is a 302 that redirects to /fr/ (The french version of this page) but leaves out the /cart/.

When I access the history page for example (domain.com?index.php?controller=history) the 302 redirects to /fr/history instead of just /fr/. (I don't know If this has anything to do with the issue)

P.S: The CartController.php file has not been changed and has no overrides.

Does anybody know where this problem might come from ?

Please help, thank you !!

Comment: have you check in seo & urls the translations for the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your htaccess and make a 301 redirect or use a module for redirecting on multilang shop (https://addons.prestashop.com/fr/url-redirections/21318-redirections-url-301-auto-repare-multishop-seo.html). I think it's a bug from Prestashop core code.

Here is the .htaccess code if necessary :

```
Redirect "/cart" "/fr/cart"
```